# Is it possible to show the website for a given device?

Tags: presentation

We have implemented a custom device `tablet` in Sitecore, and to test it we wish to render the website as if that device was in use. How do we accomplish that?

Using Sitecore 8.1

Comment: Which version of Sitecore you are using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Experience Editor (previously *Page Editor*) allows you to switch between devices. Also for the Preview mode.

> Ribbon > Experience > Click on current device > Select preferred device

[image: Screenshot - Ribbon > Experience > Click on current device > Select preferred device]

Answer (score 2):

You can switch the device manually using the built-in query-parameter `sc_device` in the url, followed by the name or ID of the device:

```
http://local.mysite.com?sc_device=tablet

http://local.mysite.com?sc_device={eb148a0f-220d-45dd-91fe-03b835e7e887}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the **Device Simulator**.

Switch to **Preview** mode, then from the `View` ribbon the `Simulator` button will be enabled and you can preview the page with a different device.

[image: Device Simulator]

This is paricularly useful if you are using Responsive Web Designs. If you are using a custom device you may also have to switch the `Device` as suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two things:

If its only about testing the device detection

- Change the device parameters in URL manually or use Sitecore ribbon menu with steps mentioned by @Dražen

If you want to test the device resolution and do click-thru testing

- Use [Sitecore Device Simulator](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/publishing/preview_and_setup/preview_a_webpage), you can use it to preview the website on some predefined devices resolutions. Here is the [Sitecore documentation link](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/publishing/preview_and_setup/preview_a_webpage)

[image: Sitecore Device Simulator]

I have heard about Sitecore's AppCenter `Page Preview Services` and `Device Detection Services` but I don't have anything yet to share on that part.